# Как переопределить функцию в шаблоне с++?

Tags: c++

```
template<class T>
class Tree{
****
public:
****
void show();
}

-----
class SomeClass{
***
public:
void show(){
 cout << 5;
}
}

-------

int main(){
Tree<SomeClass> t;
t.show();
}
```

Собственно, имеется шаблонный класс tree. Есть еще класс SomeClass, в котором есть метод show.
Создается дерево объектов SomeClass. И нужно его вывести.
Как это сделать?

Проблема в том, что таких SomeCLass будет несколько штук, я хочу в каждом определить свой метод show
И чтобы когда я обращался к Tree< SomeClass1 >.show() вызывался свой show,
для Tree< SomeClass2 >.show() - свой

Comment: А проблема то в чем? У метода Tree<T>::show(), должен быть обход, дерева, и вызовы T::show(). В зависимости от типа T, вызовится нужный show().

Comment: Дмитрий Зиненко, именно это я и хочу, только не понимаю, как реализовать...
T::show() - вот это вот  как связать ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/krveLr2M
вот как там определить t->show(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто написать эти специализации функции:

```
template<class T>
class Tree {    
public:
    //данный метод является селектором (просто выполняет вывод)
    //поэтому нужно обьявлять с const
    void show() const;
};


class SomeClass1 {  
public:
    void show() const { std::cout << 1; }
};

class SomeClass2 {  
public:
    void show() const { std::cout << 5; }
};

template<> void Tree<SomeClass1>::show() const
{
    SomeClass1().show();
}
template<> void Tree<SomeClass2>::show() const
{
    SomeClass2().show();
}
//для остальных также
//и общее определение
template <class T>
void Tree<T>::show() const
{
   std::cerr << std::endl
             << "other specializations"; 
}
int main() {    
    Tree<SomeClass1> t1;
    Tree<SomeClass2> t2;
    t1.show();
    t2.show();
    Tree<int> t;
    t.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Можно написать и одно определение:

```
template<class T> void Tree<T>::show() const
{
    T().show();
}
```

Но такое определение неразумное, так как не каждый тип имеет такой метод

Comment: Нет слов. Идеально. Это именно то, что мне нужно
Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, я понял, что можно было в шаблоне и так прописать:
T *t;  t->show();  (При этом show() не объявлен в шаблоне, а только в SomeClass)

Answer (score -2):

Возможно вам нужен виртуальный метод с полиморфизмом

```
class Tree {
public:
    virtual void show()
    {
        cout << "test 1" << endl;
    }
};
class SomeClass :public Tree {
public:
    void show() override
    {
        cout << "test 2" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Tree show;
    SomeClass base;
    Tree *weapon = &base; // &show Полиморфизм
    weapon->show();
}
```

Comment: читайте заголовок вопроса ... Причем тут наследование?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы чего минус поставили :) я предложил вариант полиморфизма потому что это может решить все проблемы которые были описаны, и не нужно усложнять код используя шаблоны.
Если человек делает намеренно сложный код, тогда это его дело, но я посоветовал как лучше и все.

Comment: во первых щаблоны классов тоже  обеспечивают полиморфизм, только это полиморфизм времени компиляции, а наследование обеспечивает полиморфизм времени выполнения (лучше уж  потратить время на компиляцию), и  к наследованию  нужно прибегнуть только тогда, когда типы логически связаны. В предложенном вами варианте  каждый производный класс является и деревом, а  каждый его обьект имеет неявный указатель на виртуальные функции, что занимает лишную память.  Так что ваш вариант не лучше, а хуже, и он не отвечает на вопрос, а  в ответах нужно отвечать на  заданный вопрос, а  не на другой...

Comment: Спасибо за вариант решения
Этот мне не подходит, потому что в лабе нужно было строго использовать шаблоны. А в целом - логичное решение)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну об этом я уже не знал, в любом случае если выбирать между удобным, красивым кодом и скоростью работы выполнения программы, я бы наверно выбрал удобства. Иначе продуктивность написания кода очень сильно падает. А как мы знаем память у человека не вечная)